# Live Horizontal Bar Chart keeps adding nodes

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I am trying to make a horizontal bar chart for test purposes which changes data in real time. I notice that nodes keep adding.

```
var dataset = [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ]
var w = 1200;
var h = 500;
var barPadding = 1;
var container = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h)
  .append("g");

var rects = container.selectAll("rect")

var yScale  = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([h, 0])

function draw(dataset, translate){

  yScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
  rects.data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i){
    return i * 12 + translate
  })
    .attr("y", function(d){
    return yScale(d)
  })
    .attr("width", 11)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return (h - yScale(d)) })

  rects.exit().remove()

}

var translate = 0

setInterval(function(){

  container.attr("transform", "translate("+-translate+",0)")
  dataset.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 30))
  draw(dataset, translate)
  translate = translate + 12
  dataset.shift()
}, 1000)
```

`rects.exit.remove()` doesn't seem to work, how can I fix this? I could not find any examples of live horizontal bar charts on d3 v5 which is what I am using here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you don't have a proper update selection, which is:

```
var rects = container.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset);
```

Because of that, all rectangles belong to the enter selection.

Here is the updated code, with the size of the update selection in the console:

```js
var dataset = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
var w = 500;
var h = 300;
var barPadding = 1;
var container = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h)
  .append("g");

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([h, 0]);

var translate = 0

draw(dataset, translate)

function draw(dataset, translate) {

  yScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
  var rects = container.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset);

  rects.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .merge(rects)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return i * 12 + translate
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return yScale(d)
    })
    .attr("width", 11)
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return (h - yScale(d))
    })

  rects.exit().remove();

  console.log("the update size is: " + rects.size())

}

setInterval(function() {
  container.attr("transform", "translate(" + -translate + ",0)")
  dataset.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 30))
  draw(dataset, translate)
  translate = translate + 12
  dataset.shift()
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you so much! this works, just one small concern, the translate values will keep increasing infinitely, isnt it possible to somehow update the values without translating them

Comment: Well, you should get rid of that completely: just use a scale. In this case, a band scale.

Comment: thanks for the tip! the only problem is if I use rangeRoundBands, my scale would look something like this var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1); x(0) would work and so would x(width) but to translate, the trick on bostock s article mentions using x(-1) which is undefined for ordinal scales, linear would work perfectly, so how do you go about it, here s that post from bostock s website that talks about using x(-1) https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/